# Black Screen for 2 or 3 seconds when alt tabbing into a full screen game

Tags: graphics-card, monitor

I've noticed recently that I've been encountering an issue when I try to alt tab into a full-screen game. The monitor that is plugged into my graphics card will turn black for 2 or 3 seconds. I've tried doing a clean reinstall of my graphics card driver and it has not changed anything. I'm on the latest drivers for my graphics card as well.

I have also noticed that the problem goes away in a few scenarios. One is if I change the refresh rate of my main monitor for 75Hz (which is supported by the monitor and shows up under advanced display settings.) to 60Hz (which matches the refresh rate of my second monitor that is running on integrated graphics). Secondly if I altogether unplug the HDMI cable from my CPU's integrated graphics, and run just one monitor plugged into my graphics card.

Lastly I've noticed that when my monitor is set to 75hz and I alt tab into the game my refresh rate changes automatically to 60Hz in the NVIDIA control panel. It changes my resolution from "1920 x 1080" under the PC section to "1080p, 1920 x 1080 (native)" under the Ultra HD, HD, SD section (this is all in the Change Resolution section in NVIDIA Control Panel).

I was wondering if any of you could help me get rid of the black screen without having to resort to those aforementioned fixes that I have found. I've left some of my pc specs below

Computer Manufacture and model: Dell XPS 8930

Motherboard: Dell 0T2HR0

Bios Version: 1.1.23 3/21/2022

CPU: Intel Core i5-9400

GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1660 Latest drivers.

Monitor 1 (main one that supports 75Hz): HP 24mh

Monitor 2 (second one that only goes up to 60Hz): Samsung S24E650

Windows Version: Windows 11 Pro